# как сделать выбор параметров метода относительно другого параметра

Tags: c#, методы

Пишу методы для обращение к различным таблицам из БД, каждой таблице требуются свои входные данные

Мне нужно чтобы при написании первого параметра `string nameTable` требовался конкретный набор параметров согласно требованию таблицы

Сейчас это реализуется набором одинаковых по функционалу методов для каждой таблицы (добавить, посчитать количество,найти то-то, удалить то-то и тд)

пример желаемого 
Есть для таблицы `User`(первый параметр `string nameTable` ) требуются данные `long id`(второй параметр) и всё, но при обращение к `ban` требуется `long id`, `string comment` и тд.

Comment: Делайте второй параметр типа `Dictionary` и передавайте коллекцию ключ-значение, либо делайте параметр типа `object` и передавайте экземпляр анонимного класса `new { id = 1000, commect = "text" }`

Comment: напишите пример пожалуйста

Comment: В самом классе работы с БД методы должны быть универсальными (не зависящими от названия таблиц и списка полей, кроме, быть может, `id`). Можно, например, сделать методы `SelectAll(tableName)`, `SelectById(string tableName, long id)` и `Select(string tableName, Query query)`, где в `Query` будет поля `string where`, `string orderBy` и т.д. Либо воспользоваться готовыми решениями, чтобы не изобретать велосипед. А если не хочется логику построения основных запросов дублировать и держать в бизнес-логике, то можно для каждой таблицы создать свой класс-обёртку с нужными методами запросов

Comment: Ваш путь ведёт к хаосу. Сделайте для каждого  типа/таблицы свои собственные методы: `User(long id)`, `Ban(long id, string comment)` - это даст вам и интеллисенс (подсказки при вводе в IDE), и строгую типизацию, и лёгкий рефакторинг, и простое понимание логики кода в дальнейшем.

Comment: Спасибо за разнесение, сейчас так и есть.Просто меня смущали одинаковые методы